# How can I check if a DataGridView contains column "x" and column "x" is visible?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I check if a `DataGridView` contains column "x" and column "x" is visible?

All I have so far is below.

```
if (Dgv.Columns.Contains("Address") & ....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The straightforward method:

```
if (dgv.Columns.Contains("Address") && dgv.Columns["Address"].Visible)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: In case you're wondering as I was, [DataGridView.Columns.Contains is case-insensitive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.name(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly verify if the column exists and then you verify its visibility.

Calling the column's property for a column that does not exist will crash.

```
if (dgv.Columns.Contains("Address")
{
    if ( dgv.Columns["Address"].Visible )
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the column visibility using the `Visible` property:

```
if (column.Visible)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

This will tell you if the column should be displayed.

You can get the column via this call if you know the index:

```
DataColumn column = dGV.Columns[index];
```

If the column is displayed but off the screen I don't know how you'd test for that.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the columns, checking the heading (I assume that's what you're looking for) and the Visible property.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var dataGridViewColumn = dgv.Columns["Address"];

 if (dataGridViewColumn != null && dataGridViewColumn.Visible)
   {
                    //do stuff
   }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)